# SQL: Performing window function and finding percent

Tags: sql, grouping, percentage, window-functions

I have a table that includes the rows Data, Gender, Age Group and Number of Fans. I need to show the split of page fans across age groups in %.

So far, I have been able to limit the data to the newest data (The most recent entry is 2018-10-06,) but have been unable to perform -- what I assume is needed -- a window function to group the genders (M, F, U) together and to then find the percent per age group. I greatly appreciate any help. Here is as far as I have gotten with success:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM fanspergenderage
WHERE fanspergenderage.date >= '2018-10-16'
GROUP BY fanspergenderage.gender, fanspergenderage.agegroup;
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWBVi.png)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all hep.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to show the split of page fans across age groups in %.

I interpret this as the proportion of all fans in each age group. You seem to be asking for something like this:

```
SELECT f.agegroup,
       COUNT(*) as num_fans,
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as ratio
FROM fanspergenderage f
WHERE f.date >= '2018-10-16'
GROUP BY f.fanspergenderage;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.